# wordpress gravity forms how check checkbox dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

i check a checkbox by below code but total price field does not change. how to fix it?
you can see the page of my problem by [this link](http://www.milad-ahmadi.com/%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%AD%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A8/). this image  describes my problem: [image]

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
gform.addAction( 'gform_input_change', function( elem, formId, fieldId, total ) {
    if(formId == 13){
        console.log(fieldId);
        if(fieldId == '1.0'){
            jQuery('input[name = "input_35.1"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
}, 10 );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering a change on the checkbox you are checking.

```
jQuery('input[name = "input_35.1"]').prop('checked', true).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Dave worked perfect. I was trying to dynamically tick a gravityforms checkbox with another input. The checkbox was visually ticking, but fields were not being hidden (which they would if I manually ticked it). The added .change() function did the trick great!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO and thanks for your contribution. I'm afraid that what you posted does not qualify as an answer, as you only ascertain that another answer worked for you. The right way to go about this it's to post a comment on the answer that worked for you and, if you can, leave an upvote (they won't be visible until you get a little more reputation but it's a good habit to pick up ;) )

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30808586)